# Как получить список установленных callback-ов в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Имеется какой-то модуль, например user-module.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.unlink('/tmp/hello', function (err) {
  // Это CallBack, который оставляет после себя модуль.
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
});    
// Таких CallBack-ов в модуле может быть много, или не быть совсем.
```

Имеется какой-то код на JavaScript. В некоторой точке код должен загрузить модуль и после этого узнать какие CallBack-и оставил после себя этот модуль. Пример:

```
var domain = require('domain');
var d = domain.create();
d.run(function() {
    require('user-module');
});
```

Как в этой точке получить список CallBack-ов, которые оставил после себя user-module. Интересуют любые способы. На JS, с помощью addon-а на C++, etc.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, привести пример того, что во подразумеваете пол коллбеками и каким образом модуль может их оставить.

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду весь код, который потенциально мог поменять модуль, то боюсь, что никак. Например, если модуль перегрузил `Array.prototype.indexOf`, и на перегрузке запускает `setTimeout`, в котором подгружает jQuery — будет ли код jQuery считаться callback'ом?

Comment: Примерно так. Под CallBack-ом понимается обработчик любой асинхронной функции, или event-а, или таймера. Но по обработчикам event-ов и таймером у меня некоторая информация есть.  Например process._getActiveHandles() выдаёт некоторые обработчики таймеров и событий. Но, к сожалению, не все. А мне нужно именно все.

Comment: CallBack-ом является то, что оставляет после себя например setTimeout. Например setTimeout(function(){/*Не важно что внутри, это CallBack*/}, 50); Но не только таймер. Любая асинхронная функция.

Comment: @VladD, речь же о node.js. Понятие коллбека в данном вопросе однозначно меппится на цикл событий (http://i.stack.imgur.com/BTm1H.png) и подразумевает любую асинхронную операцию.

Comment: @СергейБабич, не пойму, зачем такое может понадобиться. Т. е. даже если ты сможешь узнать, какие именно колбеки на данный момент создал модуль, любой из них может при своём выполнении создать ещё. Также, они могут быть вызваны несколько раз. Да и вообще, я не вижу возможности как-то использовать информацию о них.

Comment: По моему проще делать через [обещания](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) , там есть способ смотреть очередь обещаний (калбэков)

Comment: @Qwertiy "зачем это может понадобиться" - это отдельная, и достаточно обширная тема. В двух словах: есть сервер, который запускает служебные модули, и при каких-то условиях (например при перехвате ошибке именно в этом модуле) сервер должен полностью выгрузить модуль. Т.е. остановить все его таймеры, снять все его листенеры, может ещё что-то. Пока я упёрся в CallBack-и. Сам сервер при этом не должен упасть. И не должен завершить свою работу. Сервер должен аккуратно выгрузить модуль и продолжить работу. Потому что на этом сервере висит ещё с десяток таких же модулей.

Comment: @vnn198 К сожалению я не имею опыта работы с обещаниями. Плюс к этому, у меня нет возможности влиять на код контролируемого подгружаемого модуля (в примере это user-module.js), CallBack-и которого мне нужно получить. В этих модулях может быть что угодно (включая синтаксические ошибки). Если мою задачу можно решить как-то с помощью обещаний, буду весьма признателен, если вы расскажете как.

Comment: А нельзя ли это реализовать через домены?

Comment: @Qwertiy Что "это"? Получение списка CallBack-ов? Я именно это и спрашивал в начальном вопросе. Можно ли это реализовать через домены? Я изучил всю официальную документацию по доменам. Рассмотрел модуль domain.js. Погуглил. Как можно получить список CallBack-ов с помощью домена я не нашёл. Если кто-то знает как и расскажет - буду весьма признателен.

Comment: Я имел в виду, помещать каждый модуль в отдельный домен и подписываться на ошибку для этого домена.

Comment: Хм.. А что подразумевается под выгрузкой модуля?

Comment: @Qwertiy "выгрузка модуля" - это уже очень сильно уходит за рамки первоначальной темы. Что касается доменов - каждый модуль и так помещается в отдельный домен (см. пример в начале). Подписка на ошибку домена делается (в примере этого нет), но это не решает задачу получения списков CallBack-ов. Собственно обработчик ошибок домена, это и есть одно из мест, где мне нужен список CallBack-ов. И как его там получить пока не понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Никак, сущности callback на самом деле не существует (это абстракция), есть параметры функции, есть стэк.

Для того, чтобы получить какой-то интерактив, существуют promise т.е. пишите в своем модуле

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require("promise").Promise;

var promise = new Promise();
fs.unlink('/tmp/hello', function (err) {
  // Это CallBack, который оставляет после себя модуль.
  if (err) {
    return promise.reject(err);
  };
  promise.resolve('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
});
return promise;
```

а в вызывающем коде:

```
var domain = require('domain');
var d = domain.create();
d.run(function() {
    require('user-module').then(succesUser, failUser);
});
function sucessUser(message) {
     console.log(message);
}
function failUser(message) {
     throw new Error('message');
}
```

Думаю, нужно пояснить про несуществование сущности callback, возьмем код:

```js
function someFunct() {
    console.log("Hello world")
}

function runMe(parameter) {
  // paremeter - callback ?
}

runMe(someFunct);
```

```js
function someFunct() {
  console.log("Hello world")
}

function runMe(parameter) {
  console.log(parameter.toString()); // нет, это не callback
}

runMe(someFunct);
```

```js
function someFunct() {
  console.log("Hello world")
}

function runMe(parameter) {
  parameter(); // О, а это callback :)
}

runMe(someFunct);
```

как видно из примеров выше, определить, что аргумент функции является callback или не callback можно только после его запуска. Вообще понятие callback это всего лишь такое удобство для понимания, не какая-то специальная конструкция языка. Для окончательного пояснения приведу еще один пример:

```js
function someFunct() {
  console.log("Hello world")
}

function runMe(parameter) {
  eval (parameter + '()'); // omg, это тоже callback :)
}

runMe("someFunct");
```